# Generate new row data based on number

Tags: python

I have a project to generate new row data based on number. Here's the example of number

number = [2,7,3,5,..,etc]

```
rowid |  quantity | total
1         1         1
1         1         2     <-- my number
2         1         1
2         2         3
2         1         4
2         3         7     <-- my number
3         2         2
3         1         3     <-- my number
4         3         3
4         2         5     <-- my number
..       ..         ..
```

rowid present for code of data, quantity is generate random number, and the number is max of quantity that sum of previous.

I don't have any idea how to generate this data through python using iterate for function, even my number has total 60000.
anyone have any idea to help me?

Comment: Can you maybe reformulate your question? Might be just me, but I really don't get it. So the quantity is randomly generated for each line? In which range of numbers then? You mention something about sum of max of previous. How would that be initialized? 
What exactly does the total stand for? I see, that in some cases they come from your array, but what about the other rows?

Comment: as general, the number is sum of quantity each rowid. if you see rowid, it could be like date time, day1,day2, . . ., etc. Actually the number column is resulted through aggregation each rowid. Unfornutelly i dont have quantity data each day, so i want to generate it by random number

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is it what you wanted or did I miss something of your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This here would give you the expected result. I'm sure, there are way more elegant ways, but it would work here.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 2],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 3],
    [4, 2],
]

d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["rowid", "quantity"])
d["total"] = pd.pivot_table(d, index="rowid", values="quantity", aggfunc="cumsum").quantity
d
```

Here I didn't randomly generate the quantity but just took over the values you provided. So in case, you would have to take care of that yourself.

Let me know, if you have some further questions about that.

Edit: I made the solution a bit easier.